# Regex - special characters and numbers - PHP and Javascript

Tags: regex

As I have hard time creating regex that would match letters only including accented characters (ie. Czech characters), I would like to go the other way around for my name validation - detect special characters and numbers.

What would be regex that matches special characters and numbers?

Comment: What is your definition of special characters?

Comment: Well, basically everything other than number and letter. My goal is to be able to validate Firstname and Lastname

Comment: Usually `\W` works for those cases

Answer (score 0):

To specify @anubhava's, `\w` stands for `[a-zA-Z0-9_]` and capitalizing it negates the character class.  If you want to match `_` too, you'll have to make your own character class like `[^a-zA-Z0-9]` (everything but alphanumeric).  Also this can be shortened to `[^a-z\d]` if you use the `i` modifier.  Note, this would also match accented characters since they are *not* `a-zA-Z0-9`.

[Example](http://regex101.com/r/fK3iZ5)

However, I always advice against trying to use a "regular" expression to match a name (since names are *not* regular).  See this [blog post](http://www.kalzumeus.com/2010/06/17/falsehoods-programmers-believe-about-names/).